# Add list of ints to a list of lists of ints

Tags: python, list

```
h = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]

n = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0], [0, 1], [0]]
```

I want to add each int in h to each list in n, such that I get:

```
result = [[1], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2], [3, 4], 3]]
```

I have failed with:

```
z = []
for i in h:
    for i2 in n:
        k = i + i2
        z.append(k)
```

I understand why this fails but I don't know the way forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_n = [[int_n+h[i] for int_n in list_n] for i,list_n in enumerate(n)]
```

Among other solutions.

It's not very different from what you have tried, but uses a more compact syntax and takes advantage of [enumerate()](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) which you should use every time you loop on some list-like object

And what you tried doesn't work because when you do :

```
for i2 in n:
```

i2 will be each list in n, and not each integer because n is a list of lists.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !

Comment: Note that `i` is only used index `h`, so Wen-Ben's answer is more straightfoward.

Answer (score 2):

You can using

```
z=[[z + x for z in y ]for x , y in zip(h,n)]
z
[[1], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2], [3, 4], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use new result array

```
result = []

for i in range(len(h)):
    intermediate = []
    for j in n[i]:
        intermediate.append(j + h[i])
    result.append(intermediate)
```